# Add integer column to timestamp column in PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose you have PySpark dataframe with an integer type column `days` and an datetype column `start` who looks like this:

```
start                      days      
--------------------------------------
2021-04-08 02:49:09          8
2021-04-08 02:49:09          9
2020-05-05 08:43:02          7
```

What I want to become is a new column `end` who would look like this:

```
start                      days              end     
---------------------------------------------------------
2021-04-08 02:49:09          8      2021-04-16 02:49:09
2021-04-08 02:49:09          9      2021-04-17 02:49:09
2020-05-05 08:43:02          7      2020-05-12 08:43:02
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `days` into `IntervalType` and then add it to the `start` column.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("2021-04-08 02:49:09", 8), ("2021-04-08 02:49:09", 9, ), ("2020-05-05 08:43:02", 7, )]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("start", "days")).withColumn("start", F.to_timestamp("start", 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))

df.withColumn("end", F.col("start") + F.concat(F.col("days"), F.lit(" days")).cast("interval")).show()
```

### Output

```
+-------------------+----+-------------------+
|              start|days|                end|
+-------------------+----+-------------------+
|2021-04-08 02:49:09|   8|2021-04-16 02:49:09|
|2021-04-08 02:49:09|   9|2021-04-17 02:49:09|
|2020-05-05 08:43:02|   7|2020-05-12 08:43:02|
+-------------------+----+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `date_add` function to add days and concatenate the hour part to the resulting date:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "end",
    F.concat(
        F.expr("date_add(start, days)"),
        F.date_format("start", " HH:mm:ss")
    ).cast("timestamp")
)

df2.show()
#+-------------------+----+-------------------+
#|start              |days|end                |
#+-------------------+----+-------------------+
#|2021-04-08 02:49:09|8   |2021-04-16 02:49:09|
#|2021-04-08 02:49:09|9   |2021-04-17 02:49:09|
#|2020-05-05 08:43:02|7   |2020-05-12 08:43:02|
#+-------------------+----+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually easy to do this with dates but keeping the time is harder.  We use a sql expression so that we can get the columns to play together.  Here I use lots of whitespace for formatting.(runnable code below)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
     ("2021-04-08 02:49:09",8),
     ("2021-04-08 02:49:09",9),
     ("2020-05-05 08:43:02",7
  ],
  [
     "start",
     "days"
  ]
)
df.withColumn(
  'end',
  F.to_timestamp(
    F.expr("date_add(start,days) || ' ' ||split(start,' ')[1]")
  )
).show()

+-------------------+----+-------------------+
|              start|days|                end|
+-------------------+----+-------------------+
|2021-04-08 02:49:09|   8|2021-04-16 02:49:09|
|2021-04-08 02:49:09|   9|2021-04-17 02:49:09|
|2020-05-05 08:43:02|   7|2020-05-12 08:43:02|
+-------------------+----+-------------------+
```

Code in runnable format

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("2021-04-08 02:49:09",8),("2021-04-08 02:49:09",9),("2020-05-05 08:43:02",7)],["start","days"])
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn('end',F.to_timestamp(F.expr("date_add(start,days) || ' ' ||split(start,' ')[1]"))).show()
```